# Анимация переходов между активити

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-fragment, activity

Здравствуйте знатоки андроид.

Уже который день не получается сделать анимацию переходов между activity.
Имеется два активити: Activity_1 и Activity_2, в каждом из них есть по два фрагмента: Fragment_1(верхний) и Fragment_2(нижний) как показанно на рисунке. Мне нужно что бы анимация перехода между активити в первом случае (activity_1 -> activity_2) открывалась с центра вверх и вниз, и во втором случае 
(activity_2 -> activity_1) с вверха и низа в центр, т.е. фрагменты 1 и 2 соответственно поднимались и опускались.

Заранее спасибо кто сможет чем нибудь помочь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]